# JPA 2 Criteria API compare by a certain element from joined collection

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, criteria, criteria-api

Maybe the question is a bit unusual and I just don't get how the Criteria works (pretty sure because I just started to learn it) but now I am bit confused by the following issue:

I implement a filter functionality which should make possible to populate a set of records by a certain criteria. So let's assume that there are the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @OneToMany
    private List<Deal> deals; 

}

@Entity
public class Deal {

    private Customer customer;

    private DateTime dealDate; 
}
```

And now I have to filter the Car records by the **first** customer name. So in theory it would look like:

```
private static List<Predicate> buildPredicates(Root root, CriteriaQuery query,
 CriteriaBuilder builder, CarFilter filter) {
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
predicates.add(
    builder.like(            
            root.get(Car_.deals.sortByDealDateComparator().first().customer.name), 
            filter.getFirstCustomerName()));
    ...
    return predicates;
}
```

I believe that the deals should be first joined and then maybe somehow sorted by a subquery or something. But then it would also be interesting how to get the first result for the comparison using just CriteriaQuery.

I guess I am on a wrong way with that, so any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: Very confusing question. Why are you concerned with sorting the deals when you are trying to get by first name? What is the result you are getting? What do you expect?

Comment: I agree that it may be confusing. So, let's assume that the deals are not ordered in the list by any criteria. And I basically want to get the name of a customer from a deal with the oldest date.

Answer (score 0):

Well, some of your issue is because your of entity `hierarchy`. You have `Cars` at the root of your hierarchy, but you need to work with `Deals`. If you work with `Deals`, getting what you want is (more or less) straight forward:

```
CriteriaQuery<Deal> q = cb.createQuery(Deal.class);
Root<Deal> root = q.from(Deal.class);
CriteriaQuery<Deal> s = q.select(root).where(
        cb.like(root.get("customer").get("name").as(String.class), "Karl"  )
    ).orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("dealDate")));
Deal deal = em.createQuery(s).getResultList().get(0);
```

Notice of course I did not try to use the Metadata versions of the Entities. Here, the root is set to `Deal`. The `like` `predicate` is used to get `Customers` by name, and ordering is done with `cb.asc` to the resulting list of deals. The first `Deal` is taken from the result list, which will have the `Customer` in it.

If you want to get back to the `Car` you need a `bidirectional` relationship mapping, which you would do by adding `Car` to `Deal` and mapping with `ManyToOne`.

```
@ManyToOne
private Car car;
```

May or may not help, but this should give you something to think about.

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas, but probably I should have provided more details about the problem. This is just a helper method which builds predicates in order to build Specification<T> provided by Spring-Data-Jpa. So here I don't have access to entity manager. Just CriteriaQuery and CriteriaBuilder.
Also in this specific example I am not really interested in Deal, the query should return a list of Cars filtered by a property of this Deal...

Comment: No real sense in posting a question that can't be answered is there?

Comment: Kind of. I actually found a work-around, adding sequence number for each deal depending on age, so the oldest one will always have the 0 sequence.

And then get what I need using subquery.